# How to call a service in a function from another controller (Angular JS)

Tags: angularjs

I have a **Main Controller.**
I have a **client controller** and its **service**.
An ADMIN can create, get, update and delete and getList of Clients.
Now Admin logs out and Client logs in.

I want that client can view and update his profile who is logged in. (GET & PUT operations)

[image]

What I am trying to do is that from **Main Index.html** Page, when a Client clicks on **Profile** , it is nevigates to /profile and call a function as well ng-click="profile()"

Now I have created a separate profile controller in which I am creating a function **profile()** and calling **getClient** from my **Client Service**
but I am unable to call that function.

`This is sample of my code` -> [MYCode](https://plnkr.co/edit/gacR0zQ8fYQ1S8cvqwoM?p=catalogue).

**EDIT**

The sample of code is not working in plunker. My project is very large and complex so I have just exposed a little part. Plunker is just for the sake to show the logic of my code.

Help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your plunkr is not runnable. It doesn't have any ng-app, and its index.html is not even a complete HTML page.

Comment: Yes I have just exposed some part of code its not in working state. Just to show the sample of code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can go through my simple login app to get an idea of how you want to structure  your application [here](https://github.com/noman57/login.git)

Answer (score 0):

In the plunker example, your service is mispelled "ClientServie.js". Also, try make it a service instead of a factory.
Since the plunker is also not runable its hard to debug whats really going on.

Comment: yes. its just the sample of the code. Its a huge project I cannot make its plunker so just for sak eof understanding I have just shown a small part.